# Python - Inserting list of tuples into SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to take a list of tuples, created in python, and import them into a table in SQLite. The following code works:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb4.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Counts (email TEXT, count INTEGER)''')
```

However, once I try to insert the dictionary, which looks like this, and is called `Counts`:

```
[('txstate.edu', 17), ('media.berkeley.edu', 56), ('vt.edu', 110), ('whitman.edu', 17), ('lancaster.ac.uk', 14), ('rsmart.com', 8), ('fhda.edu', 1), ('uct.ac.za', 96), ('unicon.net', 9), ('utoronto.ca', 1), ('loi.nl', 9), ('indiana.edu', 178), ('et.gatech.edu', 17), ('umich.edu', 491), ('gmail.com', 25), ('ucdavis.edu', 1), ('stanford.edu', 12), ('bu.edu', 14), ('caret.cam.ac.uk', 157), ('ufp.pt', 28), ('iupui.edu', 536)]
```

With the following code, I just get a `Out[318]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x1b3e6500>`, and no change in the SQLite table.

Code:

```
cur.executemany('insert into Counts (email, count) values (?,?)',Counts)
```

I've also tried changing the tuples to dictionaries/referencing the values by name, and looping through the list running cur.execute multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to *commit* the change:

```
cur.executemany('insert into Counts (email, count) values (?,?)',Counts)
conn.commit()
```

You can have the connection take care of this automatically by [using it as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

```
with conn:
    cur.executemany('insert into Counts (email, count) values (?,?)',Counts)
```